# Filtering files with a regex pattern in Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: regex, perl, sftp

Using the
[`Net::SFTP::Foreign`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign)
module, is it possible to download only files with a specific extension. For example, all `.xml` files

What I've tried so far:

```
say "Downloading files...";

$sftp->rget(
        REMOTE_DIR,
        LOCAL_DIR,
        newer_only => 'true',
        wanted     => qr/*\.xml/
);
```

This downloads no files. If I remove the `wanted` option then all files are downloaded.

Comment: The `*` is a special character in regular expressions. Your pattern is invalid. Remove it.

Comment: Using qr/xml/ makes no difference.

Comment: adding a `.` before the `*` or simply removing `*` should do the work.

you can also add `$`at the end of the regex to specify you want `xml` at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my regex but no files get downloaded. I believe this could be related to how the "wanted" option in this Perl module should be used. If I remove the wanted option altogether, I see all files beeing downloaded including all the XML files.

Comment: It the source directory is flat (without subdirectories), you can also use `mget` which accepts names with willcards: `$sftp->set_cwd($remote_dir); $sftp->mget("*.xml", $local_dir, newer_only => 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has a syntax error. If I run it, I get this:

> Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE .xml/ at ...

That's because the `*` is a special character. It cannot stand on its own, and it is not used as a wildcard like it would be on the shell. Remove it.

A good, valid pattern for getting only XML files could be

```
qr/\.xml$/
```

The `$` denotes the end of the string, so that you would not download all files in a folder called `foo/bar.xml/baz/`.

The pattern will match everything that contains it, regardless of what comes before the match.

Comment: @r1pster: You'll have to give a little from your end. What you have been given should work and we can only make guesses about what mistakes you have made. Are you sure that you have copied the regex pattern precisely? Please give examples of some real-world files that are not being retrieved when you think they should be. Have you tried doing a case-insensitive match, with `qr/\.xml$/i`? Have you tried using the `ls` method to read what files are in that directory? Have you tried enabling verbose mode with `more => '-v'` when you create the object? There is a lot you could try.